# android - deleting characters in a string and arrayList not working properly

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Let's assume I have an `arrayList` of length 1, filled with the value `2` (`arrayList.get(0)` would return `2`).

With the below method, I'm trying to remove `2` from `arrayList`, thus making it's length 0. The method is also removing the last value from `textViewCurrExp`.

The problem I'm having is that it's not really removing the value from the `arrayList` because when another method (that displays the contents of `arrayList`) is executed, `2` hasn't been removed from the `arrayList`.

Here is the method:

```
public void backspace (View view) {
    TextView textViewCalcCurrExp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewCalcCurrExp);

    try {
        if (arrayList.size() > 0 ) {
            // removing the last item from the ArrayList
            arrayList.remove(arrayList.size() - 1);
        }

        String string = textViewCalcCurrExp.getText().toString();
        if(string.length() > 0) {
            // removing the last character from the TextView
            textViewCalcCurrExp.setText(string.substring(0, string.length() - 1));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        TextView textViewCalcCurrRes = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewError);
        textViewCalcCurrRes.setText("ERROR");
    }
}
```

So, my question is, what can I change in this method so that it does what I want it to do?

---

EDIT: here is the other method (unrelated code replaced with `//calculations happen here`):

```
public void onClickEquals (View view) {

    TextView textViewError = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewError);
    TextView textViewCalcPrevRes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCalcPrevRes);
    TextView textViewCalcCurrExp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCalcCurrExp);
    TextView textViewCalcPrevExp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCalcPrevExp);
    double calc = 0;
    String calcOutputStr;
    String tempString;
    int c = arrayList.size();
    boolean boolCalcPerformed = false;

    try {
        //calculations happen here (with the value(s) of arrayList, 
        //in this case, arrayList.get(0) == 2 when arrayList.get(0) 
        //should be null after running method above)
        //For context, if arrayList held {2,+,3}, calcOutputStr = "5"
        }
        //HERE IS WHERE the values output to textViews (in this hypothetical case 
        //calcOutputStr = "2"; because arrayList.get(0) is holding the value 2,
        //when it should be calcOutputStr = "";)
            textViewCalcPrevExp.setText(textViewCalcCurrExp.getText()); //copy text from textViewCalcCurrExp to textViewCalcPrevExp
            textViewCalcCurrExp.setText(""); //remove text from textViewCalcCurrExp
            textViewCalcPrevRes.setText(calcOutputStr); //display calc
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        textViewCalcPrevExp.setText(textViewCalcCurrExp.getText());
        textViewCalcCurrExp.setText("");
        stringInput="";
        stringInputWithOp="";
        arrayList.clear();
        textViewError.setText("ERROR");
    }
}
```

Comment: in this `if (arrayList.size() > 0)` conditional, change `arrayList.remove(arrayList.size() - 1);` to `arrayList.remove(0);` and let me know if that changes anything. It shouldn't but that's an easier way to display your code. Also, can you post your toString method?

Comment: Modifying it to remove the value at index 0 is not what I want to do, I should have clarified; I want it to remove the last value in the `arrayList`. So if there were 3 values `{2,3,4}` and this code were executed it would remove `4`.
I can add the other method but I'll truncate the unrelated code and replace it with a comment, just to save space.

Comment: try to console your `arraylist.size()` you got what is mistake .....

Comment: print out the `arraylist.size()` before enter the `try` block.

Comment: I think problem is not with the arraylist. You should log your arrayList size right after arrayList.remove() to see this size after removal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void backspace (View view) {
    TextView textViewCalcCurrExp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewCalcCurrExp);

    try {
        if (arrayList.size() > 0 ) {
            // it will remove the 2 on index 0 because your 2 is no zero index                           
            arrayList.remove(0);
        }

        String string = textViewCalcCurrExp.getText().toString();//its coming empty
        if(string.length() > 0) {
            // removing the last character from the TextView
            textViewCalcCurrExp.setText(string.substring(0, string.length() - 1));
        }else{
             // if array list is zero than set textview as "";
           textViewCalcCurrExp.setText(string.substring("");

           }


    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        TextView textViewCalcCurrRes = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewError);
        textViewCalcCurrRes.setText("ERROR");
    }
}
```

you intialy your text view does not have any value so

```
if(string.length() > 0) {
            // removing the last character from the TextView
            textViewCalcCurrExp.setText(string.substring(0, string.length() - 1));
        }
```

this condition is become false;